# Displaying array contents in pairs

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'm trying to make a website that displays all userprofiles. I want to wrap every two users in a `<div>`, until there is no left. So say we have 19 arrays consisting of userprofileinfo in $info - the following code will work fine, but will print out the 20th out as an empty div, which I want to prevent. What to do here?

```
$info = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

for ($count = 0; $count <= mysqli_num_rows($result) - 1; $count += 2) {
    echo <div class="row">
    echo "<div>".print_r($info[$count])."</div>";
    echo "<div>".print_r($info[$count+1])."</div>";¨
    echo </div>
}
```

Comment: I know the echo statement itself may seem weird, posting arrays inside divs, but the intention is to show that I wouldn't want an empty <div> to show.

Comment: What's wrong with a simple `if` to check if `$count + 1` index exists? Though given you just do the same for both echos, I'm unsure why you wouldn't just do one by one rather than count+2. Also, remember to close your closing div tags.

Comment: I could - that just didn't seem like a concise solution..

Comment: I'm not sure how much more concise you can get than "if this do x else y" :P

Comment: You're right... Just thought there was a kind of better solution to it with a loop I maybe didn't know about. Thank you for your help, I will do this!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just to provide a slightly cleaner version of Yvan1263's answer using OPs updated code (having fixed quotes).

```
$info = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

for ($count = 0; $count <= count($info) - 1; $count += 2) {
    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo "<div>".print_r($info[$count])."</div>";
    if (isset($info[$count+1])) {
        echo "<div>".print_r($info[$count+1])."</div>";
    }
    echo </div>
}
```

Comment: using mysqli num rows makes *absolutely* no sense here.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Sure, but it's part of the code given to us by OP and has nothing to do with the problem? I mean, if that's the reason for whoevers downvote, I don't see how it makes the answer "not helpful".

Answer (score 1):

I think you might overthinking this. Why not simply use `array_chunk()`?

```
$info = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach (array_chunk($info, 2) as $chunk) {
    echo '<div class="row">';
    foreach ($chunk as $element) {
        echo "<div>".$element['name']."</div>";
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

The way `array_chunk()` works is that it will group the array elements into chunks of a given size. You can have a double loop. The inner loop will iterate on each chunk and display both elements.

Answer (score -2):

You can just do this:

```
$info = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

for ($count = 0; $count <= mysqli_num_rows($result); $count += 2) {
    if($count+1 >= mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
        /* IF MAX IS MORE THAN ENTRIES NUMBER */
        echo "<div>".print_r($info[$count])."</div";
    }
    else {
        echo "<div>".print_r($info[$count])."</div";
        echo "<div>".print_r($info[$count+1])."</div";
    }
}
```

NB: Use PDO instead of MySQLi.

Comment: I want to group every two users into a <div class="row">, so this solution won't work

Comment: The edit it over-complicated. OP will always want to do the first one, so no need to have a separate if for it.

Comment: @Jonnix : You can edit my post to implement your answer if you want.

Comment: @Yvan1263 Then it would be my answer, not yours ;)

Comment: I see what you mean Jonnix. So add an if statement to check if $count + 1 exists, and if not (else), just print one.

Comment: I've added an answer just to show. It's just a cleaned up version. And I don't see why this should mean OP should use PDO over MySQLi, that seems irrelevant to the question.